# org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.setVersion Unknown version string [4.0]. Default version will be used

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

pleas help me
i cant deployed war file in intellij idea..

> .25-Sep-2018 22:54:12.407 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1]
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.setVersion Unknown
>   version string [4.0]. Default version will be used. 25-Sep-2018
>   22:54:12.476 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1736)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:483)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:432)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:202)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:199)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:198)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:567)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named
>   [edu.owl.gplus.LoginServlet] and [edu.wol.gplus.LoginServlet] are both
>   mapped to the url-pattern [/login] which is not permitted     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMappingDecoded(WebXml.java:326)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:319)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2379)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2056)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1942)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1936)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1936)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1936)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1143)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:765)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 44 more
>
> 25-Sep-2018 22:54:12.491 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1]
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception
>   invoking method manageApp  java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:758)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1736)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:483)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:432)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:202)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:199)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:198)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:567)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> 25-Sep-2018 22:54:12.491 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1]
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception
>   invoking method createStandardContext 
>   javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method
>   manageApp     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:308)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:483)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:432)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:202)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:199)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:198)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:567)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:758)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1736)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>     ... 35 more
>
> [2018-09-25 10:54:12,516] Artifact owl:war exploded: Error during
>   artifact deployment. See server log for details. 25-Sep-2018
>   22:54:21.753 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory
>   [H:\owlda.com\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\webapps\manager] 25-Sep-2018
>   22:54:21.853 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory
>   [H:\owlda.com\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\webapps\manager] has finished in
>   [100] ms

Comment: Those   are not working...

Comment: Please help me i cant deployed it.. war: explorer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> We can't use java servlet within spring web MVC  if we are trying to do that we can get that error.